# Different Output through gcc and clang complier

Tags: c, gcc, clang, post-increment, pre-increment

**so i compline this code in C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a = 1;
   printf("%d",a++);
   printf("%d",a);
   printf("%d",++a);

   int b =1;
   printf("\n%d%d%d",b++,b,++b);

}
```

**out in gcc**
*123*
*233*

**out in clang**
*123*
*123*

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of *undefined behavior*.

Comment: It is one of the most frequent duplicates here. OP did not even try to do any research

Comment: On a different note, please make it a habit to print *trailing* newlines rather than leading. If `stdout` (which is where `printf` writes) is connected to a terminal, then it's *line buffered*. That means output is actually written on newline. When you print a leading newline then you writ the *previous* line, not the current one.